# Demystify example code from playframework (Security.scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

In the file https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Security.scala, it has the following example code in a comment:

```
 //in a Security trait                                                                    
 def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")                     
 def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)
 def isAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
   Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
     Action(request => f(user)(request))
   }
}                                                                                       
//then in a controller                                                                   
def index = isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    Ok("Hello " + username)
}
```

So I tried to write some similar code:

```
def test1(a: =>Int=>Int=>Int):String="1"
test1 {1 => 1 => 1} // But this line doesn't compile.
```

I called it the same way as `isAuthenticated` is called, so why doesn't my code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test1 {1 => 1 => 1}` doesn't compile because `{1 => 1 => 1}` isn't a valid function definition. `{x => y => 1}`, on other hand, does compile. This is because `1` cannot be used as the name for a parameter.

Comment: Is "username => implicit request => Ok("Hello " + username)"  a valid funcition? username is not a parameter but "def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")", so what's the meaning of "username => implicit request => Ok("Hello " + username)"

Comment: Actually, `username` is a parameter. `username` the parameter shadows the `def username` outside, so inside the function, `username` references that parameter, not the `def username`.

Comment: Many thanks, and In "username => implicit request => Ok("Hello " + username)" has a implicit. How to use it? I  tried the following simple example, but I can't figure out a way to don't assign the implicit parameter.
implicit val x:Int=10
def fun(a: Int=>Int=>Int=>Int)=1
fun(a=>b=>implicit c=>a+b+c)  ==> here I used implicit c, but any way to figure out a case when no explicit assign of c is required?

Comment: When a function has a parameter marked `implicit` it only makes it available as an implicit value inside of that function. Only methods can have implicit parameters that the compiler sets automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what happens when you paste `def test1(a: =>Int=>Int=>Int):String="1"` into the  Scala REPL:

```
test1: (a: => Int => (Int => Int))String
```

`test` becomes defined as a function that accepts an another function as it's parameter. Notice the extra parenthesis in the REPL output. `a` is a function that maps `Int` to *another function* `Int => Int`.

So something like this would be more appropriate:

```
def a(i: Int): Int => Int = {j: Int => i + j}

test1(a)
```

Comment: why "isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    Ok("Hello " + username)" could be compiled? username  is the def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")